# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT / GROUP BY issue

Tags: mysql

I have an issue regarding a GROUP_CONCAT / GROUP BY utilisation :

Let's say I have 3 tables like this :

tickets_table :

| id_ticket | date_ticket |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/1970 |
| 2 | 02/01/1970 |

items_table :

| id_item | label_item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item 1 |
| 2 | Item 2 |

tickets_items :

| id_ticket | id_item | pu_item | qty_item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 |

With a GROUP_CONCAT statement I would like to have something like this :

| id_ticket | date_ticket | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/1970 | [Item 1, qty: 4, total: 12], [Item 2, qty: 2, total: 8] |
| 2 | 02/01/1970 | [Item 1, qty: 6, total: 18], [Item 2, qty: 8, total: 32] |

By using this command, I obtain an error #1111 - Invalid use of group function :

```
SELECT
    tt.*,
    (SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("[", it.label_item, ", ", sum(ti.qty_item), ", ", sum(ti.qty_item * ti.pu_item), "]"))
     FROM tickets_items ti
     INNER JOIN items_table it ON it.id_item = ti.id_item
     WHERE ti.id_ticket = tt.id_ticket
     GROUP BY it.id_item) items
FROM tickets_table tt
```

And and error #1142 - Subquery returns more than 1 row, when i remove sum functions

If someone wants to try here is the code to construct the dabatase as fast as possible :

```
CREATE TABLE tickets_table (id_ticket int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, date_time date NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE items_table (id_item int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, label_item varchar(30) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE tickets_items (id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, id_ticket int(11) NOT NULL, id_item int(11) NOT NULL, pu_item int(11) NOT NULL, qty_item int(11) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO tickets_table (id_ticket, date_time) VALUES (1, '1970-01-01'), (2, '1970-01-02');
INSERT INTO items_table (id_item, label_item) VALUES (1, 'Item 1'), (2, 'Item 2');
INSERT INTO tickets_items (id_ticket, id_item, pu_item, qty_item) VALUES (1, 1, 3, 2), (1, 1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 3, 3), (1, 2, 4, 1), (1, 2, 4, 1), (2, 2, 4, 4), (2, 2, 4, 4);
```

Just a few more things:

- The attribute pu_item can change over the same ticket so there is no possibility to merge qty_item into one line and get it from items_table
- There is other tables linked to the id_ticket from the tickets_table, that's why I have to do a subquery in the SELECT * FROM tickets_table (like all payments done for example)

Thanks in advance for your helps !

Comment: No need for a subquery, using a `JOIN` in combination with grouping on more than one column (`GROUP BY id_ticket, id_item`) alongside `SUM` with your `GROUP_CONCAT` could achieve this. Though in all honesty, that's a lot more complex than dealing with the data in your application, understanding that SQL will return "multiple" records for a unique set of joined data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tt.id_ticket, group_concat(val)
FROM tickets_table tt
join (
SELECT ti.id_ticket, CONCAT("[", it.label_item, ", ", sum(ti.qty_item), ", ", sum(ti.qty_item * ti.pu_item), "]") val
     FROM tickets_items ti
     INNER JOIN items_table it ON it.id_item = ti.id_item
     GROUP BY ti.id_ticket, it.id_item
         ) B ON (tt.id_ticket = B.id_ticket)
group by tt.id_ticket
```